# Error with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have to remove the text in the title tag from this source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Microsoft to acquire Nokia’s devices &amp; services business, license Nokia’s patents and mapping services</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9; IE=10" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta id="ctl00_WtCampaignId" name="DCSext.wt_linkid" />
    </title>
```

I am using this to remove the text:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

ourUrl = opener.open("http://www.thehindubusinessline.com/industry-and-economy/info-tech/nokia-cannot-license-brand-nokia-post-microsoft-deal/article5156470.ece").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)
print soup
dem = soup.findAll('p')
hea = soup.findAll('title')
```

This code correctly extracts the p tags however fails when trying to extract title. Thanks. I have only included a part of the code, dont worry the rest of it works fine.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem; the HTML on that page is broken, but both BeautifulSoup 3 and all 3 parser plugins for BeautifulSoup 4 give me the correct output and I can extract the title just fine.

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup are you using? The 4.0 series had some problems. Also, some lxml + libxml2 combinations have problems with certain HTML input. If you are using BeautifulSoup 4, do you have lxml installed at all?

Comment: Umm, what errors do you get? Or you get an empty list? Because I tried your code (and this page too), and got **no** errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your html code! You have 2 `</title>` endtags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Microsoft to acquire Nokia’s devices &amp; services business, license Nokia’s patents and mapping services</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9; IE=10" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta id="ctl00_WtCampaignId" name="DCSext.wt_linkid" />
    </title> #You already have endtag of <title>
```

So the fixed code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Microsoft to acquire Nokia’s devices &amp; services business, license Nokia’s patents and mapping services</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9; IE=10" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta id="ctl00_WtCampaignId" name="DCSext.wt_linkid" />
```

Comment: The HTML is loaded from an external URL, I doubt the OP can correct the page. The goal is to extract the title from the broken HTML source without fixing it.

Comment: Yeah i added the last </title> cause i couldn't copy the entire source. Sorry about that, but why doesn't findall work. Its bs4 by the way.

Comment: You know, try just `soup.find("something")`